# How to align text and image side by side in phpWord?

Tags: php, phpword

I need to align a logo and text side by side. But when generating the word document, the text always comes beneath the logo image.I tried the solution pointed out here: 
http://phpword.codeplex.com/discussions/232684

But it didn't work for me.
Here's what i tried (not the solution mentioned above)

```
$section = $PHPWord->createSection();
$image = $section->addImage('_mars.jpg',array ('width'=>100));
// Add table
$table = $section->addTable(); 
for($r = 1; $r <= 1; $r++) { // Loop through rows
    // Add row
    $table->addRow();
    for($c = 1; $c <= 1; $c++) { // Loop through cells
      // Add Cell
     //I tried adding image in this line.
     $table->addCell(1750)->addText("Row $r,Cell ".
$section->addImage('_mars.jpg',array('width'=>100)));
    }
}
```

and I'm getting this error in

```
$section->addImage() partCatchable fatal error: Object of class PHPWord_Section_Image could not be converted to string in
```

Can anyone tell me how I can add image in table cell ?

Answer (score 8):

You should use text run :

```
$section = $PHPWord->createSection();
$image = $section->addImage('_mars.jpg',array ('width'=>100));
// Add table
$table = $section->addTable(); 
for($r = 1; $r <= 1; $r++) { // Loop through rows
    // Add row
    $table->addRow();
    for($c = 1; $c <= 1; $c++) { // Loop through cells
        // Add Cell
        $cell = $table->addCell(1750);
        $textrun = $cell->createTextRun();
        $textrun->addText("Row $r,Cell ");
        $textrun->addImage('_mars.jpg',array('width'=>100));
    }
}
```

Link : [TextRun](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/master/samples/Sample_04_Textrun.php#L22)

Answer (score 0):

Please use this article , its does not support byt default so you can use this tutorial to create image like functionality 
http://www.shotdev.com/php/php-com-word/php-word-add-insert-picture-addpicture/